# Prove $||A||_2 = max_{x \neq 0, y \neq 0}\{\frac{|\langle y,Ax \rangle|}{||x||\cdot ||y||}\}$ for $A\in \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I'd like to prove that the spectral norm of a matrix that is not necessarily square can be written as the following subordinate norm

$||A||_2 = max\{\frac{|\langle y,Ax \rangle|}{||x||\cdot ||y||}, y \in \mathbb{K}^n\backslash\{0\}, x \in \mathbb{K}^m\backslash\{0\} \}$ for $A\in \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$

where $\mathbb{K}$ is $ \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

I started doing the following:
$||A||_2 = max_{||v||_2 = 1} ||Av||_2 = max_{||v||_2 = 1}\langle z,Av\rangle^2$ for $z=Av$ but I feel like I'm going down the wrong path. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can try using SVD

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite know what to do with that information. SVD leads me to: $||A|| = max_{||v||=1} \langle v, V \Sigma^2 V\text{*}v\rangle$ which I don't know what to do with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** 
$$
\|A\|_2=\max_{\|v\|_2=1}\|Av\|_2, \quad
\|w\|_2=\max_{\|z\|_2=1}\left|\langle z,w\rangle\right|.
$$
Use the second in the first.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared everything up!